# Self Signed Certificate: connection timeouts

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, tcp, network-programming

I have a web application (Apache 2.4 on Centos 7 server) that has limited user access and I am using Self Signed Certificate with Client Certificates (mutual authentication) for each user. Everything works great; users are authenticated successfully, Chrome shows green https in the address bar since I added certs as trusted. I can revoke clients, identify clients from their connection in my application etc...

However, in different time intervals, connection is interrupted. Let say I have Chrome opened 5-10 minutes and wanted to navigate somewhere in the application, and Chrome says connection is lost and reloads the page itself and I can continue with the page I wanted to go. That's ok but when I use Ajax it is a big trouble because Ajax request fails or even does unexpected things in the background.

I have SSLSessionCacheTimeout increased to 8 hours!

I know I should tell you the actual error when it happens, I know but until then all I can say it claims about a DNS_ error, it doesn't ask for resending client certificate, nothing about client cert as I can see but of course not sure. I will get the actual error on Monday from an authenticated machine if it doesn't make sense without actual error or point to an obvious problem with this much information.

What am I supposed to do? Having really hard time with this. Any pointer will definitely make my tomorrow better. Thank you!

Comment: Connection timeouts don't have anything to do with certificates whatsoever, or SSL, or SSL session timeouts either.

Comment: Same application has no interruption without SSL. That's why I am counting on that it has something to do with certificate. With SSL it kind of tries to refresh the connection between client and server.

Comment: No. Once the connection is established the certificate is irrelevant.

Comment: @EJP: After your certain and solid answer I changed my path to find the problem. Do you think keeping KeepAliveOn disabled might be causing this problem? I actually turned it on to test but just wanted to give an update about my nightmare. Thank you.

Comment: I mean, I had KeepAlive Off, now I turned it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all about Chrome. Returned error is ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED. I even checked chrome://net-internals logs and it complains about SSL HANDSHAKE and CLIENT CERTIFICATE even I don't get the entire problem but understand that Chrome is not OK with Client Certs. Anyway, it doesn't happen in Internet Explorer, so it is certainly Chrome problem. Therefore the answer is "Don't use Chrome for the applications requires Client Certificate". I was even ok to live with selecting "only" client certificate whenever I open the chrome to access my application which IE also has solution for that.

If anybody comes up with a solution then it would be perfect but until then, I'll switch to IE for making things work.